# Why are there two different values for the size of a drive and how to reconcile them with device-mapper and LVM?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, lvm, device-mapper, hdparm

I have a 1 TB drive attached via USB. It contains an LVM *physical volume* filling the entire device (without any partition table). When I tried to extend a **logical volume** by using the entire PV, the *device-mapper* started to complain that the section allocated by LVM on the PV is larger than the device. The error message from the device-mapper (as shown by `dmesg`) reports a size of **1953320367** [dm] sectors:

```
device-mapper: table: 254:0: sdf too small for target: start=1821353984, len=132169728, dev_size=1953320367
```

But LVM created a PV with 238467 *physical extents*, which is **1953521664** [lvm] sectors (which is about 100 MB more):

```
$ pvdisplay /dev/sdf
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf
  VG Name               apu-vg1
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 1.71 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238467
  Free PE               100
  Allocated PE          238367
  PV UUID               LrKDDW-4dXz-kDgh-CK78-OWhY-4sCH-rKT0e4
```

Now if I run `hdparm -gI` on the device, I can see two values for the size of the device. Under *geometry*, there's the same value that is reported by the device-mapper as the device's size. But under *LBA48 user addressable sectors*, there's the value **1953525168** [lba], which is less than one PE larger than the combines size of the PEs of the PV. This makes me think that this is the value that LVM sees:

```
$ hdparm -Ig /dev/sdf

/dev/sdf:
 geometry      = 121588/255/63, sectors = 1953320367, start = 0

ATA device, with non-removable media
          Model Number:       ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB                  
          Serial Number:      S2RUJ9BC702524      
          Firmware Revision:  2AR10001
          Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
Standards:
          Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0028) 
          Supported: 8 7 6 5 
          Likely used: 8
Configuration:
          Logical         max     current
          cylinders       16383   16383
          heads           16      16
          sectors/track   63      63
          --
          CHS current addressable sectors:   16514064
          LBA    user addressable sectors:  268435455
          LBA48  user addressable sectors: 1953525168
...
```

Now to my questions:

- Why are there two different values for the device's size used by different parts of the kernel?
- And, how do I handle/fix this situation so that the LVM will not make PVs that are larger than the space the device-mapper is willing/able to access?

Comment: what's the exact command that you're running when you extend? LVM heads are usually allocated 2MB which is around the size of your discrepancy.

Comment: The smaller size reported by `hdparm` is the largest number that's a multiple of 255*63 sectors and less than the actual size. This constraint is due to the cylinder/head/sectors format from the 30 year-old BIOS interface. The newer LBA48 interface can report the size of your disk just fine. I have no idea why Linux uses the CHS size for anything.

Comment: I labeled the different values in square brackets to easily refer to them.

Comment: @JoelDavis I extended the VG using a plain `vgextend <vg-name> /dev/sdf`. LVM does exactly what I expect. `pvdisplay` even says that __1.71 MiB__ are unusabe, which is exactly the size of the difference between [lvm] and [lba].

Comment: @Feuermurmel please [edit] your question to provide additional information - don't use comments.

Answer (score 1):

The key problem here is your `Free PE` value. Notice how it says that only 100 extents are free? That means that you won't be able to extend it. If you do a vgscan, pvscan, and then a vgdisplay (also vgs) you will probably see that your device is already part of a vg (and likely lv(s) as well), which is why the extents are not free.

Could you provide the output from:

`vgscan;pvscan;vgdisplay;vgs`

you should be able to get an additional 400MB based on the size of your extents and how many are free.

Comment: Yes, that PV already has 238367 PE allocated to an LV. Those 100 extends are free because I shrunk the LV after the device-mapper complained about the mapping requested by LVM being out of range. My problem is that the PV created by LVM is actually _larger_ than the physical disk. That disk in question is no longer part of the system so I can't provide the output you requested.